# If $\cos t =−3/5$, where $\pi <t< 3\pi/2$, what is $\sin(t/2)$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I have tried the following:

```
1) Sin(t) = (-4/5) 
2) sin(t) = 1-2(sin^2(t/2)) 
3) (-4/5) = 1-2(sin^2(t/2)) 
4) ((-4/5)-1)/(-2) = sin^2(t/2)
5) -9/10 = sin^2(t/2)
(Note: the step below is where I seem to go foul, since we cannot square root negatives.)
6) sqrt(-9)/sqrt(10) = sin(t/2)
```

I can't seem to figure out what I have done wrong that has led me to square root a negative. Any suggestions?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Step 5. Negative divided by negative is positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, your mistake $\sin t\ne 1-2\sin^2 \frac{t}{2}$

Use the following formula
 $$\cos t=1-2\sin^2 \frac{t}{2}$$
$$\sin \frac{t}{2}=\pm \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos t}{2}}$$
$$\sin \frac{t}{2}=\pm \sqrt{\frac{1-\frac{(-3)}{5}}{2}}=\pm\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}$$
But, $\pi<t<\frac{3\pi}{2}\iff \frac{\pi}{2}<\frac{t}{2}<\frac{3\pi}{4}\implies \sin\frac{t}{2}>0$ hence, 
$$\color{red}{\sin \frac{t}{2}=\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Full angle $t$ is in third quadrant, so sine of half angle in first quadrant

$$= \sqrt {\frac { 1- \cos t }{2}   } =  \frac{+2\sqrt 5}{5} $$